# Does Hex apply to Spiritual Weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cleric, warlock

If I use Hex (PHB p251) on a creature and next turn I use, say Eldritch Blast as my action and Spiritual Weapon (PHB p278) as my bonus, would Spiritual Weapon also get hex's extra damage?
I'm a bit confused by the wording of what's 'me' and what's 'mine'.

Answer (score 25):

**Yes.**

From *hex*:

> Until the spell ends, you deal an extra 1d6
>   necrotic damage to the target whenever you hit it with
>   an attack.

From *spiritual weapon*:

> When you cast the spell, you can make a melee spell
>   attack against a creature within 5 feet of the weapon.

*You* are considered to be making the attack when you attack with *spiritual weapon*; *you* deal an extra 1d6 damage when you hit a target with an attack.  Therefore, *you* deal that extra damage when you hit your target, whether with *eldritch blast* or *spiritual weapon*.

Comment: Or a _punch to the face_.

Comment: One fun fact, is that because the wording of Hex does not state a limit on attacks, Hex scales with EB damage, because differently from most other cantrips, EB rolls multiple times for attack.