# Does Armor of Agathys work for melee spell attacks like Spiritual Weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack, melee-combat

[*Armor of Agathys*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/armor-of-agathys) (PHB 215) states:

> If a creature hits you with a melee attack while you have these hit points, the creature takes 5 cold damage.

Since it doesn't specify that it has to be a weapon attack, does it also work for melee spell attacks?

Specifically, would it work against *[Spiritual Weapon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/spiritual-weapon)* (PHB 278)?

Comment: Related: "[Is a melee spell attack also a melee attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/112213)" and "[Does Hex apply to Spiritual Weapon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107379)" and "[What is a "Melee Spell Attack" and how does it differ from a regular spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50029)"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Yes, it works for melee spell attacks

A Melee Spell attack is still a melee attack. Melee attacks are melee attacks, but there can be different types (weapon, spell, etc.)

As long as it is a melee attack, then *armor of agathys* will trigger.

#### Yes, it will work for *Spiritual weapon*

This was actually more complicated than I thought it was going to be based on determining who is actually making the attack. While *spiritual weapon* is not a creature, and normally wouldn't trigger the *armor of agathys*, it is *not* the weapon that is delivering the attack.

Instead, the caster of *spiritual weapon* is the one actually delivering the spell attack.  *Spiritual weapon* is (emphasis mine):

> ...a floating spectral weapon... When you cast the spell, **you can make a melee spell attack against a creature** within 5 feet of the weapon.

Had the language say ***it** makes a melee spell attack*, then *armor of agathys* wouldn't trigger as the attack isn't coming from a creature. But the language here is that you, a creature, are making the spell attack.

The *spiritual weapon* is basically allowing your character to make a melee attack against someone on your turn at a distance.

Comment: Whereas this is totally ludicrous and not likely intended it is how it is worded. I won't allow the damage to be dealt at my table but the temp hp will be reduced just like ranged.

Comment: @Slagmoth I can add counter examples with Bigby's, but i'm not sure that it wasn't intended. BUt I hate dealing with intent anyway.

Comment: It should also trigger for *thorn whip*.

Answer (score 9):

### *[Armor of Agathys](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/armor-of-agathys)* works for melee spell attacks.

[*Spiritual Weapon*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/spiritual-weapon) (PHB 278):

> When you cast the spell, you can make a melee spell attack against a
>   creature within 5 feet of the weapon.

A melee spell attack is a melee attack, see [Melee Attacks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MeleeAttacks) (PHB 194):

> a melee attack allows you to attack a foe within your reach. [...] A
>   few spells also involve making a melee attack. [...] Most creatures
>   have a 5-foot reach and can thus attack targets within 5 feet of them
>   when making a melee attack.

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of complicated. I definitely agree it works for melee spell attacks, for they are still melee attacks. But, spiritual weapon doesn’t require you to be in melee range. I personally wouldn’t rule it triggering, but really, it’s up to the DM (like everything else).

Comment: Hello Laec, welcome to RPGSE.  SE Q&A sites are not discussion forums.  [Ask] and [answer] guidance is available. please revise your answer to the question so that it stands on its own as an answer.